# document.execCommand Losing focus no image insert

Tags: javascript, html

so I am building a VERY simple WYSIWYG and everything else works and is working well but I am having some slight issues with the image uploading - I have a folder called 'uploads' directly next to the file in the same directory location to test - I get a prompt popup asking for the path and I enter the name of a doc which I know lives in the uploads file BUT when I enter the path and confirm It seems like it loses focus and posts nothing at all into the iframe?

This is the function:

```
function iImage(){
    var imgSrc = prompt('Enter image Location', 'example.jpg');
    if(imgSrc != null){
        editor.document.execCommand("insertImage", false, "../../uploads/" + img);
    }
}
```

Here is the button:

```
 <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onClick="iImage()" title="Image Upload"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></button>
```

And here is the iFrame:

```
  <iframe name="editor" id="editor" style="height: 600px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Well. You should check the URL of the iframe. Also we'd need your 'insertImage' function.

Comment: Is that not the function above...?

Comment: I don't think so, because if it IS it's calling itself.

Comment: That might b why it isnt working - how would i get around that..I have no other functions?